# How can i make a fixed column inside a table for android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make the column that contains the value five. It is in the far right side as shown in the picture, I want it to be fixed and not 
moving.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/fillable_area">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >


             <HorizontalScrollView
               android:id="@+id/scroller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/scrollable_part"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

            </HorizontalScrollView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>



    package com.example.freez_t00;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean showSummaries;

    private TableLayout summaryTable;
    private TableLayout frozenTable;
    private TableLayout contentTable;
    private Button backButton ;
    private HorizontalScrollView hor;
    private TextView recyclableTextView;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






           TableRow.LayoutParams wrapWrapTableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            int[] fixedColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20,20, 20, 20};
            int[] scrollableColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 30, 30};
            int fixedRowHeight = 50;
            int fixedHeaderHeight = 60;
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            //header (fixed vertically)
            TableLayout header=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_header);

            row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
            row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col1", fixedColumnWidths[0],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col2", fixedColumnWidths[1],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col3", fixedColumnWidths[2],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col4", fixedColumnWidths[3],fixedHeaderHeight));
            row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col5", fixedColumnWidths[4],fixedHeaderHeight));

            header.addView(row);


            hor = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroller);
            hor.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    hor.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                }
            }, 1L);

          //  TableLayout fixedColumn = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_column);
            //rest of the table (within a scroll view)
            TableLayout scrollablePart = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                   row = new TableRow(this);
                   row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
                   row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                   row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                   row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 1", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
                   row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 2", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
                   row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 3", scrollableColumnWidths[2], fixedRowHeight));
                   row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 4", scrollableColumnWidths[3], fixedRowHeight));
                   row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 5", scrollableColumnWidths[4], fixedRowHeight));
                   scrollablePart.addView(row);
            }








    }




     public TextView makeTableRowWithText(String text, int widthInPercentOfScreenWidth, int fixedHeightInPixels) {
            int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            recyclableTextView = new TextView(this);
            recyclableTextView.setText(text);
            recyclableTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            recyclableTextView.setTextSize(20);
            recyclableTextView.setWidth(widthInPercentOfScreenWidth * screenWidth / 100);
            recyclableTextView.setHeight(fixedHeightInPixels);
            return recyclableTextView;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use two tables. One that scrolls. Another with that one column?

Comment: thanks for you , i will try , but can you post code xml here

Comment: I don't know if it'll work, so I don't have any code

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fillable_area"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollable_part"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>



package com.example.freez_t00;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView recyclableTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableRow.LayoutParams wrapWrapTableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    int[] fixedColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20,20, 20, 20};
    int[] scrollableColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20};
    int fixedRowHeight = 70;
    int fixedHeaderHeight = 70;
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    //header (fixed vertically)
    TableLayout header=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_header);

    row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
     row.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col1", fixedColumnWidths[0],fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col2", fixedColumnWidths[1],fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col3", fixedColumnWidths[2],fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col4", fixedColumnWidths[3],fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col5", fixedColumnWidths[4],fixedHeaderHeight));

    header.addView(row);

    //  TableLayout fixedColumn = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_column);
    //rest of the table (within a scroll view)
    TableLayout scrollablePart = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 1", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 2", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 3", scrollableColumnWidths[2], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 4", scrollableColumnWidths[3], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 5", scrollableColumnWidths[4], fixedRowHeight));
        scrollablePart.addView(row);
    }
}

public TextView makeTableRowWithText(String text, int widthInPercentOfScreenWidth, int fixedHeightInPixels) {

    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    recyclableTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    recyclableTextView.setText(text);

    recyclableTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    recyclableTextView.setTextSize(20);
    recyclableTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    recyclableTextView.setWidth(widthInPercentOfScreenWidth * screenWidth / 100);
    recyclableTextView.setHeight(fixedHeightInPixels);
    return recyclableTextView;
}
```

}

This may be help to you.
I just reform your code.